# What does a folder that starts with ".aws" mean?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-cli

What does a windows folder that begins with an "." mean?

I had an issue with AWS that needed the `.aws` folder for authorization. It wouldn't let me create it. I had to download an eclipse with the AWS SDK to create it.

Comment: Are you using a Linux/UNIX OS? If that's the case, it means the file is hidden.

Comment: Just so you know, you *can* create a folder that starts with ".". You just can't do it from Explorer. If you open a command prompt, cd to the directory you want it created in, and run "mkdir .aws" then it will create it.

Comment: You can also create them in the explorer. Create them with a normal name "dir" and then rename them ".dir." (with an additional ignored dot at the end): http://superuser.com/questions/64471/create-rename-a-file-folder-that-begins-with-a-dot-in-windows

Comment: Install AWS cli and run command "aws configure" this will create the .aws file you need for the AWS Java sdk

Answer (score 4):

Folder starting with `.` means they are hidden folder. In Windows or Linux you can create them from command-prompt using `mkdir .<folder name>` command.

If you install `aws-cli` and then run `aws configure` command then this folder will be created automatically in your home folder. you need to supply **default aws region, aws access and secret key** on the command prompt when you run above command. once you provide that it will create below two files in `.aws` folder :-

**config
credentials**

and your supplied AWS access and secret key will be there in credentials file. AWS uses this as an authorization mechanism and whatever the access your Access key and secret key has will be applied to you. it comes very handy when you directly access the AWS resources using command line or create AWS client programmatically.

P.S :- Refer http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/installing.html , on how to install `aws-cli`.

Answer (score 1):

This naming convention comes from Unix-like operating systems where it means a hidden file or directory. There is not easy to create a folder like this in Explorer, but you can create it using the command line.

If you want to read more you can consult this link: [Link](http://www.howtogeek.com/232348/why-do-some-windows-file-and-folder-names-have-a-dot-in-front-of-them/)

Answer (score 0):

In Windows, it means nothing. Probably the software you're using or developing has Unix/Linux origins (where dot in the beginning means that a file should be hidden) and simply uses the same conventions on Windows. It is true that you can not easily create a folder name beginning with dot on Windows. For further reference on how it could be done, please consult [this](https://superuser.com/questions/331921/how-do-i-create-a-folder-name-that-starts-with-a-dot-in-windows-7).

Comment: "." means a hidden file or directory in windows

Comment: @farrelmr No, it does not. That's a convention that's not used on Windows. Please consult eg. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_file_and_hidden_directory#Unix_and_Unix-like_environments) for reference.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with Java. Folders and Files starting with . are hidden on Linux/Unix systems. Sometimes this is used for build system or setting files or directories.

Windows Explorer does not like those filenames very much, but besides that those are normal directories or files. In your case I guess it contains some Amazon Credentials from some API or command line tool. If you want to manage them, use the command prompt or an alternative file manager.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response How do I close a question here?

Comment: I for got to add - Thank You Very Much

Comment: @AlabamaMothman I think you can accept a answer (15mins after asking it). You can and should also upvote all answers. http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

Thank yall for all your answers. They were ALL good answers. How do I post a question as answered.